# How to change font size of geom_text post ex

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I want to change the font size of a `geom_text` I can use the `size` parameter. But what if I have a `ggplot` object which is generated by somebody else (in a function say) and I want to change the font size *afterwards*? (I could rewrite the function and allow for an additional size parameter, but I want to avoid that).

I played with `theme(text = element_text(size = 20))`, but this changed every text, but the `geom_text`? I also tried to replace the respective layer by a new `geom_text` layer. However, since in the foreign function call the data argument for the `geom_text` was altered, I get an error about missing aesthetics.

**Code**

```
library(ggplot2)
functionICannotControl <- function() {
   mdat <- mtcars
   mdat$cyl2 <- LETTERS[mdat$cyl]
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_text(aes(label = cyl2), data = mdat)
}
(bp <- functionICannotControl())

## changed only other text elements
bp + theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
## gives an error
bp2 <- bp
bp2$layers[[1]] <- geom_text(size = 20)
bp2
## Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label
bp2$layers[[1]] <- geom_text(aes(label = cyl2), size = 20)
bp2
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'cyl2' not found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I found the solution (and for reference, if somebody is having the same problem). We can change the `aes_params` slot of the layer:

```
bp$layers[[1]]$aes_params
## named list()

bp$layers[[1]]$aes_params$size <- 20
bp
```

N.B. It does help to write a minimal working example because by posing a well structured question, you can learn something about your own problem ;)

Comment: For others who come across this and are new to working with layers (like me!), note that you may need to look in a different index of plot$layers depending on the plot. For example, I was working with a plot where .$layers[[1]] was related to the geom_bar() layer rather than the geom_text() layer. Amazing to find this question in the depths of SO--thank you!